# How to implement transactions in Meteor Method calls

Tags: meteor

Suppose I have 2 collections "**PlanSubscriptions**" and "**ClientActivations**". I am serially doing a insert on both the collections.

Later one depends on previous one, if any of the transaction fails then the entire operation must rollback.

How can I achieve that in Meteor 1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself.

I added a package `babrahams:transactions`

At server side Meteor Method call, I called `tx` Object that is globally exposed by the package. The overall Server Side `Meteor.method({})` looks like below.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {PlanSubscriptions} from '/imports/api/plansubscriptions/plansubscriptions.js';
import {ClientActivations} from '/imports/api/clientactivation/clientactivations.js';

Meteor.methods({
    'createClientSubscription' (subscriptionData, clientActivationData) {
            var txid;
            try {
            txid = tx.start("Adding Subscription to our database");

            PlanSubscriptions.insert(subscriptionData, {tx: true})

            ClientActivations.insert(activation, {tx: true});

            tx.commit();

            return true;
        } catch(e){
            tx.undo(txid);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

With every insert I had added `{tx : true}`, this concluded it to be a apart of transaction.

**Server Console Output:**

```
I20170523-18:43:23.544(5.5)? Started "Adding Subscription to our database" with
transaction_id: vdJQvFgtyZuWcinyF
I20170523-18:43:23.547(5.5)? Pushed insert command to stack: vdJQvFgtyZuWcinyF
I20170523-18:43:23.549(5.5)? Pushed insert command to stack: vdJQvFgtyZuWcinyF
I20170523-18:43:23.551(5.5)? Beginning commit with transaction_id: vdJQvFgtyZuWcinyF
I20170523-18:43:23.655(5.5)? Executed insert
I20170523-18:43:23.666(5.5)? Executed insert
I20170523-18:43:23.698(5.5)? Commit reset transaction manager to clean state
```

For more Information you can goto link : https://github.com/JackAdams/meteor-transactions

> **NOTE**: I am using Meteor 1.4.4.2

Answer (score 2):

Since MongoDB doesn't support atomicity, you will have to manage it with Method Chaining.

You can write a method, say, `transaction` where you will call `PlanSubscriptions.insert(data, callback)`. Then in the callback function you will call `ClientActivations.insert(data, callback1)` if the first insertion is success and in `callback1` return truthy if second insertion is succes, otherwise falsy. If the first insertion returns error you don't need to do anything, but if the second insertion returns error then remove the id got from the insertion in first collection.

I can suggest following structure:

```
'transaction'(){
    PlanSubscriptions.insert(data, (error, result)=>{
        if(result){
            // result contains the _id
            let id_plan = result;
            ClientActivations.insert(data, (error, result)=>{
                if(result){
                    // result contains the _id
                    return true;
                }
                else if(error){
                    PlanSubscriptions.remove(id_plan);
                    return false;
                }
            })
        }
        else if(error){
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton! you replied to my question. I liked you solutions as well, what do you think about the answer that I posted as well above, I get it executed properly as well and atomicity of entire transaction is maintained? I would really appreciate if you put light on my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I'm a bit reluctant to use any extra package when it can be solved easily with minimal effort. I've seen your answer, it might work too.

Comment: Upvoted as your implementation doesn't require any other extra package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in Meteor, since mongodb is not an ACID-compliant database. It has a single-document update atomicity, but not a multiple-document one, which is your case with the two collections.
From the mongo documentation:

> When a single write operation modifies multiple documents, the modification of each document is atomic, but **the operation as a whole is not atomic** and other operations may interleave.

A way to isolate the visibility of your multi-document updates is available, but it's probably not what you need.

> Using the $isolated operator, a write operation that affects multiple documents can prevent other processes from interleaving once the write operation modifies the first document. This ensures that no client sees the changes until the write operation completes or errors out.
>   An isolated write operation **does not provide “all-or-nothing” atomicity**. That is, an error during the write operation **does not roll back all its changes that preceded the error**.

However, there are a couple of libraries which try to tackle the problem at the app-level. I recommend taking a look at [fawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fawn)

In your case, where you have exactly two dependent collections, it's possible to take advantage of the two phase commits technique. Read more about it here: [two-phase-commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing this link for future readers:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-transactions-with-mongodb-meteor-methods/48677

```
import { MongoInternals } from 'meteor/mongo';

// utility async function to wrap async raw mongo operations with a transaction
const runTransactionAsync = async asyncRawMongoOperations => {

    // setup a transaction
    const { client } = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;
    const session = await client.startSession();
    await session.startTransaction();
    try {
        // running the async operations
        let result = await asyncRawMongoOperations(session);
        await session.commitTransaction();
        // transaction committed - return value to the client
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
        console.error(err.message);
        // transaction aborted - report error to the client
        throw new Meteor.Error('Database Transaction Failed', err.message);
    } finally {
        session.endSession();
    }
};
```

```
import { runTransactionAsync } from '/imports/utils'; // or where you defined it

Meteor.methods({
    async doSomething(arg) {
        // remember to check method input first

        // define the operations we want to run in transaction
        const asyncRawMongoOperations = async session => {

            // it's critical to receive the session parameter here
            // and pass it to every raw operation as shown below
            const item = await collection1.rawCollection().findOne(arg, { session: session });
            const response = await collection2.rawCollection().insertOne(item, { session: session });

            // if Mongo or you throw an error here runTransactionAsync(..) will catch it
            // and wrap it with a Meteor.Error(..) so it will arrive to the client safely

            return 'whatever you want'; // will be the result in the client
        };

        let result = await runTransactionAsync(asyncRawMongoOperations);
        return result;
    }
});
```